# Java application connecting to many SQL nodes

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, performance

I have a java application running on tomcat.
I want to connect it to my MySQL cluster.

In the cluster I have three SQL nodes.
I want to attempt a connection to all three nodes and then take the connection that returns to me the fastest!

How can i go about doing this? Performance is really important to me.

Here is what i have thus far:

A connector class

```
    public class Connecter extends Thread {

    String dbURL;
    String dbDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Connection dbCon = null;

    public Connecter(String dbURL) {
        this.dbURL = dbURL;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Class.forName(dbDriver);
            try {
                dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "root", "");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        }
    }

}
```

A closer class

```
public void run() {
        try {
            dbCon.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {}
    }
```

And a DbBean attempting to connect via this method:

```
String dbURL1 = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.3/bank";
String dbURL2 = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.4/bank";
String dbURL3 = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.5/bank";
String dbDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private Connection dbCon;

public boolean connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InterruptedException {
    Class.forName(dbDriver);

    Connecter one = new Connecter(dbURL1);
    Connecter two = new Connecter(dbURL2);
    Connecter three = new Connecter(dbURL3);

    Closer a = new Closer (one.dbCon);
    Closer b = new Closer (two.dbCon);
    Closer c = new Closer (three.dbCon);

    one.start();
    two.start();
    three.start();

    while(one.isAlive() && two.isAlive() && three.isAlive()){
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }

    if(one.dbCon != null) {
        this.dbCon = one.dbCon;
        two.interrupt();
        b.start();
        three.interrupt();
        c.start();
        return true;
    } else {
        one.interrupt();
        a.start();
    }
    if(two.dbCon != null) {
        this.dbCon = two.dbCon;
        one.interrupt();
        a.start();
        three.interrupt();
        c.start();
        return true;
    } else {
        two.interrupt();
        b.start();
    }
    if(three.dbCon != null) {
        this.dbCon = three.dbCon;
        one.interrupt();
        a.start();
        two.interrupt();
        b.start();
        return true;
    } else {
        three.interrupt();
        c.start();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Isn't your JDBC driver (or J2EE DataSource) supposed to take care of this for you?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this manually, and the overhead/complexity cost will not be worth any benefit. Until you've identified that this is a *actual* bottleneck (which seems unlikely on the face of it), I don't think I'd pursue this. Besides, it'd be more important to try to get the machine able to service your query the fastest, which isn't the same as which one can get you a connection the fastest.

Comment: @VictorSorokin Hi i am really clueless about how i can implement this with the out of the box functionality of the driver. Do you have any examples of a configuration that makes me try to connect to multiple SQL Nodes? A link will do! thanks!

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the advice but How can I automatically do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use database which supports connection pooling (any modern RDBMS supports this) and use out-of-the-box solution, such as `DataSource` or c3p0.

See, for example, [official JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/datasource.html#1000417).

One thing I'm not sure about, is whether you want pool of connections or more advanced clustering. But, anyway, I doubt MySQL can provide production-stable clustering and, as far as I know, Oracle supports clustering transparently, by means of it's JDBC driver.

Comment: Thanks for this but after looking through for hours yesterday this solves my problem: jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://192.168.0.3,192.168.0.4,192.168.0.5/bank
I just need to connect to this url. Other optimizations can be done to this. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: @Nikunj it's strange that load balancing is configured on the application side. The master node (balancer) should accept every request and then route it to the optimal node - resolved by some balancing strategy.

Comment: @Victor I think connection pooling doesn't have anything to do with the RDBMS. The RDBMS itself isn't aware that it's connections are being pooled - it is an application side (application server) feature.